# Woocommerce and PayPal billing address

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

Is it possible to retrieve billing address entered in PayPal checkout form and automatically save it as user's billing address in Woocommerce database?

Answer (score 2):

There is a place in WooCommerce to change the setting of whether PayPal receives the billing address or shipping address:
WooCommerce>settings>Checkout>PayPal scroll down & check the box that says

"Shipping details
Send shipping details to PayPal instead of billing."

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're working with Express Checkout as opposed to the PayPal Standard that comes with WooCommerce by default..??

PayPal's system will only return the shipping address back to the application.  This is part of the protection PayPal provides buyers...not sharing true billing info with all the different sellers they buy from.

If you want to populate the billing address fields in WC you can, but you would just have to use the same address you get for the shipping address from PayPal since that's the only address they would ever send.